# Is there a way to configure the routing client for all the requests in Spring Cloud Gateway?

Tags: netty, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I need to understand if we can replace the default Netty HttpClient to forward the requests from a Spring Cloud Gateway application to the downstream services and use some other client, let's say WebClient.

Comment: You'd have to rewrite NettyRoutingFilter and 
NettyWriteResponseFilter. I made an attempt, but haven't pursued it. See WebClientHttpRoutingFilter and 
WebClientWriteResponseFilter here https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/tree/master/spring-cloud-gateway-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/gateway/filter

Comment: Thanks for your reply @spencergibb.
I am assuming that we would have to set the order to HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE for this to work?